# unit testing static methods using powermock

Tags: java, unit-testing, powermock

I want to write unit test case for some of the static methods in  my project,

Snippet of my class code,

```
Class Util{
  public static String getVariableValue(String name)
  {
     if(isWindows()){
       return some string...
     }
     else{
       return some other string...
     }
  }

  public static boolean isWindows(){
    if(os is windows)
       return true;
    else
      return false; 
  }

}
```

Basically, i want to write unit test case for getVariableValue() when isWindows() returns 'false'. How do i write this using powermock?

Comment: Do you need to return `false` for `isWindows()` and test the `getVariableValue()` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// This is the way to tell PowerMock to mock all static methods of a
// given class
PowerMock.mockStaticPartial(Util.class,"isWindows");

expect(Util.isWindows()).andReturn(false);
```

Answer (score 4):

This solutions also uses Easymock to setup the expectation.
First you need to prepare you testclass:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(Util.class)
public class UtilTest {}
```

Mock the static class:

```
PowerMock.mockStaticPartial(Util.class,"isWindows");
```

Setup an expectation:

```
EasyMock.expect(Util.isWindows()).andReturn(false);
```

Replay the mock:

```
PowerMock.replay(Util.class);
```

Make the call to the method you want to test and afterward verify the mock with:

```
PowerMock.verify(Util.class);
```