# How to mock an exception which has some calls in it

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, powermock

I have to test a func() which throws a Exception.

The Constructor of Exception is like this:

```
Exception(){
var a = ContextHolder.get("Domain");
setDomain(a);
}
```

now when the function is throwing the Exception what i am doing:

```
try{
fun();
}
catch(Exception e){

}
```

but it shows an AssertionError that unexpected call get("Domain") which is inside Exception constructor.

Is there any way to verify that exception.

Comment: What does the `var` do?

Comment: var is just a data type, treat it as String

Comment: I wouldnt put any complex code in an exception constructor. That is bound to cause problems.. Why dont you do the domain code in the catch block instead?

Comment: What is `ContextHolder` and why does calling a method on it give you an `AssertionError`?  Is it an EasyMock mock or something?  Please tell us more about what you're actually doing.

Comment: yes i am using easymock and i have to test this fun(). ContextHolder is just somewhere we can get data required

Comment: @Oliver this is because of sending some data with exception to upstream, there are more setters in exception constructor, i have just pasted one

Comment: If all that you're interested is fun() AND the Exception class cannot be modified, then you could mock the Exception() constructor with PowerMockito. See https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockitoUsage13#How_to_mock_construction_of_new_objects

Answer (score 0):

You have to mock the contextHolder and expect the `get("Domain")` call on the `contextHolder`. In [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18613193/unit-testing-static-methods-using-powermock/18615030#18615030) I answered a similar question, mayby you can use it.

Comment: I added a link to a previous answer.

Comment: Actually, I'd say NOT mocking contextHolder would work better.  The problem seems to be that contextHolder is a mock and it doesn't need to be.

Comment: @DavidWallace I understand your point, but we can't be sure, with the given code, that the contextHolder should or shouldn't be a mock. So I presumed Kapil had a good reason to use a mock object.

Comment: We can't be sure of anything from the code.  Which is why I haven't posted an answer.  Like, is `ContextHolder` a class, of which `get` is a static method?  Or is it a variable of some kind?  All we know is that it's "somewhere we can get data required", whatever that means.  I find the question unanswerable in its current form.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like C# code, but its tagged with Java. Please confirm.
If its C# you can use a Mocking framework like Moq. Moreover, you will have to re-factor your code to remove static function calls - they are not testable!

Comment: static funtion calls are testable

Comment: it looks like Javascript. What is this 'var' ? Is this something new in Java?

Comment: @TomJonckheere yes, you are correct. Static functions are testable only a bad practice when it comes to having a little bit of flexibility. Also, I have a feeling that this static function was created only to save some keystrokes.